# How to select a w3.css class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, w3.css

I have these buttons:

```
<ul id="db-history">
    <li class="menupont"><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="1ho">1 hónap</button></li>
    <li class="menupont"><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="1het">1 hét</button></li>
    <li class="menupont"><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="48ora">48 óra</button></li>
    <li class="menupont"><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="24ora">24 óra</button></li>
    <li class="menupont"><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="1ora">1 óra</button></li>
    <li class="menupont"><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="most">most</button></li>
</ul>
```

And this click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".w3-button w3-red").click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});});
```

How to get this work? I think this is valid. I worked with w3.css classes, as you see. The selector is wrong I think, because if I put simple "button" to the selector, it works.

Comment: Try `$(".w3-button.w3-red")` you were missing a dot...

Answer (score 2):

You have to change `.w3-button w3-red` to `.w3-button.w3-red`

```
.w3-button w3-red
          ^ <- is missing the dot.
```

Now with the dot.

```
.w3-button .w3-red
          ^ <- remove the space to select an element with BOTH classes
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".w3-button.w3-red").click(function(){
    alert(this.id);
});});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="db-history">
    <li class="menupont"><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="1ho">1 hónap</button></li>
    <li class="menupont"><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="1het">1 hét</button></li>
    <li class="menupont"><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="48ora">48 óra</button></li>
    <li class="menupont"><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="24ora">24 óra</button></li>
    <li class="menupont"><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="1ora">1 óra</button></li>
    <li class="menupont"><button class="w3-button w3-red" id="most">most</button></li>
</ul>
```